# How can we convert a function without a parameter into a one-parameter function?

Tags: design-patterns, functional-programming, f#

https://www.slideshare.net/ScottWlaschin/fp-patterns-ndc-london2014 says

> Bad news: Composition patterns  only work for functions that have one parameter!
>
> Good news!  Every function is a  one parameter function!

We can convert a function with two parameters into a function with one parameter, by partial application. For example

```
let add x y = x + y 
let add x = (fun y -> x + y)

let add1 = (+) 1  
let three = add1 2
```

How can we convert a function without a parameter into a one-parameter function?

Comment: a) What do you want to achieve? Which functions do you want to compose? b) Which one is your function without a parameter? `three` is not a function, it is only a value.

Answer (score 6):

There are no functions without parameters, and there's no conversion going on with multi-parameter functions. As the quote says, "every function *is* a one parameter function". There's always just one parameter, no more and no less.

What you might consider a no-parameter function is probably a function that takes a single parameter of type `unit`:

```
let f () = ...
```

The `unit` type has only one value, `()` (which is also called "unit"), hence it carries no information, but it's still technically a value. You might think of it as the empty tuple.

A two-parameter function is actually a function that takes one parameter and returns another function that takes another parameter. Functions are first-class, remember, meaning they are values that can be returned from functions and bound to variable names. These two forms are therefore equivalent, the former is just syntax sugar for the latter:

```
let f a b = ...
let f = fun a -> fun b -> ...
```

A three-parameter function is a function that returns a function that returns a function, and so on. This is called currying. And, with curried functions, partial function application is just ordinary function application. The function application just happens to return a function rather than some other value.

Comment: Thanks. How is the composition pattern implemented in terms of functions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860184/how-can-we-implement-the-composite-pattern-in-terms-of-functions

Comment: And just to further clarify, a function of the form `let f (a,b) = a + b` is not a function with two parameters, but a function with one parameter of type `int * int` or 
"int 2-tuple".